# Quiero hacer un Slider de Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

por ejemplo tengo el segmento de código para que funcione el Slider y no funciona:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  console.log('el contenido ha cargado!');

  var ima = [];

  ima[0] = "imagenescafe/Cafe1.jpg";
  ima[1] = "imagenescafe/Cafe2.jpg";
  ima[2] = "imagenescafe/Cafe3.jpg";
  ima[3] = "imagenescafe/Cafe4.jpg";
  ima[4] = "iamgenescafe/Cafe5.jpg";

  var recorre_imagenes = 0;

  function cambiarImagenes(); {
    document.slider.src = ima[recorre_imagenes];
    if (recorre_imagenes < 4) {
      recorre_imagenes++;
    } else {
      recorre_imagenes = 0;
    }
  }
  setInterval(cambiarImagenes, 2000);
});
```

Comment: tienes un `;` al lado de tu función `cambiarImagenes()`, solo quítalo y prueba.